# Port forwarding on Airport Express

Tags: port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, sftp, airport-express

I want to be able to access files on my new Raspberry Pi remotely. So I enabled sftp, but I cannot manage to access it remotely. Here are the details of the setup:

- I can access sftp on the Pi from my local network.
- My router is an Apple Airport Express, and port forwarding is set up. I know it can work as I am using it successfully with Microsoft Remote Desktop. For sftp-ing the Pi, I forwarded the sftp port to the local IP. I tried both port 22(router)->22(pi) and 8022->22.

If I dont do the port forwarding, the sftp client returns connection refused. When I enable the port forwarding, it always times out?!

Am I missing something here? Any advice/comments more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: can you access to TTY using SSH protocol?

Comment: not 100% sure of what that means, but just as sftp, I can ssh onto the pi locally, but not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. It is because the pi is always connected to a VPN server, and all traffic is router through it.